# React deleteing from state array

Tags: javascript

I'm working on my first to do app with React. Trying to create delete function that allows a user to click the task and have it removed from the array and UI.

I've been trying a couple of different things following other's tutorials, but no luck. (Check commented out sections)
My console.log within the deleteItem function is showing undefined, so I know that it's not receiving the right data. I'm lost as to why.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { List } from './list';

export class Todo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            term: '',
            items: []
        };
        this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
    }
    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({term: e.target.value});
    }
    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (this.state.term === "") {
            alert("You must enter something!");

        } else {
            this.setState({
                term: '',
                items: [...this.state.items, this.state.term]
            })
        }
    }

    deleteItem(index){
        // var filteredItems = this.state.items.filter(function (item) {
        // return(item.index !== index);
        // });
        // console.log(filteredItems);
        // this.setState({
        // itmes: filteredItems
        // })

        this.setState({items: this.state.items.filter(function(item){
            console.log(item.index)
            return item !== item.index
        })})
        console.log(this.state.items)
        // if (item.index === index) {
        //     var indArr = this.state.items.indexOf(item.index);
        //     this.state.items.splice(indArr, 1);  
        // }

    }


    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h3>You currently have {this.state.items.length} things to do.</h3>
                <form className="Todo" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <input placeholder="Enter task" value={this.state.term} onChange={this.onChange} />
                    <button>add</button>
                </form>
                <List items={this.state.items} delete={this.deleteItem}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

List.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export class List extends Component {   
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);
    }
    delete(key) {
        this.props.delete(key);
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <ul>
                {
                    this.props.items.map((item, key) => <div class="listItems" 
                        onClick={(e) => this.delete(item.key)}
                        key={key}>{item}</div>)
                }
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Can you please update `delete` to something else, as it a `keyword`

Comment: if you are checking console output in your deleteItem function, that is wrong again.... 
write console.log(this.state.items) as callback to setState()..

Comment: Furthermore, you are adding string to the items array, It'll be difficult for you to delete strings from the array, probably you'll need a json entered in the array, with some unique key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found there are some problems in your code.

TD:LR

```
// List.js
onClick={(e) => this.delete(item.key)
// instead => 
onClick={() => this.delete(item)

// App.js
return item !== item.index
// instead => 
return item !== index
```

This is my code link, you can have a look:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n2uy9z

**1. Pass wrong value to this.delete in List.js**

```
onClick={(e) => this.delete(item.key)
```

The `item.key` is array index, you should pass `item` which you want to delete. And the params `e` is not need because you use `item`.

**2. The filter callback function is not right**

```
this.setState({items: this.state.items.filter(function(item){
      console.log(item.index)
    return item!== item.index
})})
```

The `item.index` is undefined, because `item` is a value in array, it has no `index` property. The value will be deleted is `index` which is passed to function `deleteItem`, so you should use return `item !== index`.

**3. Invalid DOM property `class`.**

This is a waring in `<div class="listItems"`: 'Warning: Invalid DOM property `class`. Did you mean `className`?'.

So use `className` instead of `class`.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you. Solved every error I had. Still new to React so I appreciate the description of each change.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're binding the delete function to the wrong component. Try removing `this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);` in the List.js class and just calling `this.props.delete(key)` directly from the onClick function

Comment: I gave it a go, now I'm seeing this.

todo.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
todo line 38

Comment: Is your list component rendering at all?